# How can I improve my filtered Loop of Objects with lodash?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am looping through `issues` in the data filtered by a condition.

```js
const rowObjects = Object.keys(data).filter((list) => {
  let issueRow = data[list];
  let destroyFilter = list._destroy:
    return !destroyFilter ? list : null;
}).
map((issue, key) => ({
  console.log(key + 1)

}));
```

I am wondering if there is a way todo this with lodash?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving the design of working code belong on CodeReview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Use `_.filter()`. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter

Comment: `_.filter` can be called directly on an object, you don't need to use `Object.keys()`. The function receives the key and value as arguments.

Comment: Not that lodash is bad or anything, to me it would seem your going backwards. Your ES6 stuff looks simple and easy to follow, it doesn't need another library if run on modern browsers, and more people are likely to understand it.  btw.  If your want to iterate/filter/map etc using `key/value` pairs there an easier way than Object.keys..

Comment: @Barmar its a real question?

Comment: @Keith what is the easier way?

Comment: @EmbetIsit use entries instead eg. Use this as a template -> `Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key,value]) => console.log(key,value))`  You can use this for map / filter / reduce etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this, I just learned actually.

```
const filter = _.pickBy(data, (list) => {
 return //whatever you want 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, from what I can gather you have your data as an object literal, you then mark the key's you don't want with a `_destroy` tag.

You then want another object literal without the one's marked `_destroy`.

Below is a version that does that without lodash,. 
There might be an easier way in lodash, not sure. But the ES6 way to me just looks so natural, and easy to follow.  It could even be made to look simpler by splitting out bits into utility functions, eg. the last reduce could be used in other places were you want key / value, transformed back into an object literal.

ps. If you don't mind modifying the original object literal, this is even easier, and most likely better performance.  Things like React I believe like deterministic data, so deleting in-place might not be an option.

```js
const data = {
  a: {
    _destroy: true,
    value: "destroy this"
  },
  b: {
    value: "Keep Me!!"
  }
};

const data2 = 
  Object.entries(data).
  filter(([key, value]) => !value._destroy).
  reduce((obj, [key, value]) => (obj[key] = value) && obj, {});

console.log(data2);
```